# Allowing ports using iptables fails

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, bash, port

I have been trying to write a bash script to quickly open and close ports as I want on my Debian server using iptables. I want to quickly switch between "Maintenance mode" and "Server - Gameplay mode" by using my script because I will be running a game server. Please pardon my noobness on this, as I am not very experienced with Linux...

Essentially, I will be running three separate game server instances which runs on different ports on their own.

- Server A needs 32000 TCP + UDP *and* 32005 TCP
- Server B needs 33000 TCP + UDP *and* 33005 TCP
- Server C needs 34000 TCP + UDP *and* 34005 TCP
- Also, by default I am allowing ports 80 and 443 TCP for web stuff (for some reason they keep getting disabled - I am still working on it).

After executing my script, port 80 opens up just fine, but I cannot get the remaining ports open for some reason....

Here is the last state of my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
RED='\033[0;31m'
YELLOW='\033[1;33m'
GREEN='\033[1;32m'
ORANGE='\033[0;33m'
GREY='\033[1;30m'
NC='\033[0m'

echo -e "${ORANGE}Starting default server iptables script${GREY}"

set -o xtrace

iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F

iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

#Web ports configuration
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT

#A server ports configuration
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 32000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 32000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 32005 -j ACCEPT

#B server ports configuration
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 33000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 33000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 33005 -j ACCEPT

#C server ports configuration
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 34000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 34000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 34005 -j ACCEPT

iptables -I INPUT 1 -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -j DROP

#Save the iptables
eval "iptables-save > /etc/iptables/rules.v4"

set +o xtrace
echo -e "\n\n\nScript finished executing...! :-)${NC}"
```

I am using [this website](https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) to check if my port is open or not.

If you could point out my errors, I'd really appreciate it, because I've been trying to figure out for two days now :-(

**EDIT:** I've just downloaded nmap and ran a scan for all tcp ports. For some reason, my port 32005 is open but the rest is closed. I am now very, very confused :) Please see the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: As good as being able to write your own rule set script by hand is, why not write simple service definition files for `ufw` ? then simply `ufw allow gameserver1` delete the appropriate entry

Comment: @ivanivan my main reason for doing this is so that I can learn and understand a bit more rather than relying on tools and such. I've used ufw and sure, worked fine but I want to understand how I'd script such thing to give me a better understanding of "port management" or whatever you'd call it :)

Comment: Understanding what's going on is all well and good, but we don't recommend trying to write firewalls yourself for anything going into production. Besides, it's easy enough to understand a `ufw`-generated firewall, and it will actually work.

Comment: Alright then, if that is the consensus, can someone please write such answer so I can accept and close the topic to prevent further confusion with people? I guess I should experiment with these stuff actually on my local Linux instance rather than my production VPS! Thanks guys.